# Is it possible to merge attributes from lines which are on top of each other?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, spatial-join

I was able to merge the different kinds of roads (verharding lijn) with the normal roadmap (Wegen 1.0).

The attributes were copied to all the records, but there are empty attributes where the kind of road should be given.

Is there a way to combine these two lines? Or even just copy the cooresponding attributes from verharding lijn to Wegen 1.0?

[image: Feature from Wegen 1.0]

[image: Feature from verharding lijn]

Comment: In ArcGIS for Desktop this would be [Overlay Route Events](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1%20/index.html#//003m00000009000000) - perhaps look into QGIS Linear Referencing options.

Comment: @boll - Awesome buddy! Will post the comment as an answer for the convenience of others :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the **Join attributes by location** tool from the toolbar:

*Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location*

The tool also let's you choose whether to keep either matching fields or all fields from both layers:

[image: Join attributes by location]

Answer (score 3):

Try using the combine tool (samenvoegen) from the advanced digitizing tools (geavanceerd digitaliseren). You have to select these two lines, click the combine button, and than it asks you what the attributes should be.